# How to securely randomize the order of the characters in a string?

Tags: perl, random

```
[user@notebook ~]$ echo 'aabcd' | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>' | perl -pe 's/\n//g';
cdaab[user@notebook ~]$ echo 'aabcd' | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>' | perl -pe 's/\n//g';
dbaac[user@notebook ~]$ echo 'aabcd' | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>' | perl -pe 's/\n//g';
cbada[user@notebook ~]$ echo 'aabcd' | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>' | perl -pe 's/\n//g';
adcba[user@notebook ~]$
```

AFAIK this is a secure way to randomize the order of the strings. **But can it be done with only one perl command?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "one perl command".  It certainly can be done with some refactor of your approach:

```
echo abcde | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lpe '$_ = join "", shuffle split //'
```